# Distinguishing between form inputs

Tags: html, apache, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have several inputs (file) in my html form. Is there any way on my servlet when the form is submitted that I can get the name attribute of the file tag? I'm asking because the form has 2 different sections for uploading forms, and I need to put the forms into 2 different categories when I process them in the Servlet, and I'm hoping to use the input name prefix to tell what section of the form the file came from. I have prefixes on the input 'name' attributes, but I'm not sure how I can get that on the servlet.

I know with a traditional form, with say an input of type text, I can say: request.getParameter("myInputName") and get the object, but I'm not sure how to handle this with file inputs.

Comment: I've got the same problem -- numerous forms which should be distinguished.  Wish I knew how to do that, and hope someone answers.